# How to remove button correctly using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have block with 8 container's(`project_block`) and  with **slick slider**.Also in bottom I have a small button.

**Slick slider** trigger only in `990` pixels. And when it start to slide I need to *remove button which in bottom*.But how to remove that button that he's place not be empty.?

When I remove with method `btn.remove()` button place is stay in my slider like this look at white area in left side  [image]

Please Help

Here is [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/LrYZWL) snippet

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 990) {
    $('.container-slick').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      infinite: true,
      prevArrow: false,
      nextArrow: false,
      speed: 200,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 568,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }]
    });
  }
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 990) {
    $('.container-slick').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      infinite: true,
      prevArrow: false,
      nextArrow: false,
      speed: 200,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 568,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }]
    });
  } else {
    $(".container-slick.slick-initialized").slick("unslick");
  }
});
```

```css
.projects {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.projects .projects_title {
  font-family: 'montserrat';
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10%;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 2.69;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #2a323d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.projects .projects_title span {
  color: #ffb338;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.projects_block {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.projects_block .project_block {
  width: 23%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
  transition: background-image, box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-image: none;
  margin: 0 1%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 58% 30%;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .projects_block .project_block {
    width: none;
  }
}

.projects_block .project_block:first-child {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.projects_block .project_block:last-child {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.projects_block .project_block:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
}

.projects_block .project_block:hover .project_title {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.projects_block .project_block:hover .project_name {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.projects_block .project_block .project_title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666666;
}

.projects_block .project_block .project_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #2a323d;
}

.projects_block .project_block a {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.projects_block .project_block:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffb338;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.project_block:nth-child(1):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
}

.project_block:nth-child(2):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
  background-position: 78% 0%;
}

.project_block:nth-child(3):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
  background-position: 78% 0%;
}

.project_block:nth-child(4):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
}

.project_block:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.project_block:nth-child(5):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
}

.project_block:nth-child(6):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
}

.project_block:nth-child(7):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
  background-position: 50% 100%;
}

.project_block:nth-child(8):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 15px 16px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #151515, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url(https://milan-holidays.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/milan_tournimage_16_1920x1015.jpg);
  background-position: 17% 60%;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .container-slick {
    max-width: 90% !important;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .projects_block .slide {
    max-width: 95% !important;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    margin: 0 -20px !important;
    outline: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width:555px) {
  .container-slick {
    max-width: 95% !important;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .projects_block .slide {
    max-width: 95% !important;
    margin: 0 -30px !important;
    outline: none;
  }
}

.btn_container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="projects_block container-slick no-padding">
      <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
        <h6 class="project_title">Festival</h6>
        <div class="project_name">Discover Milan's religious sites</div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">View &rarr;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
        <h6 class="project_title">Festival</h6>
        <div class="project_name">Saint Petersburg Philharmonic Orchestra</div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">View &rarr;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
        <h6 class="project_title">Festival</h6>
        <div class="project_name">Grand Hall Music </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">View &rarr;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
        <h6 class="project_title">Festival</h6>
        <div class="project_name">Hand-made art & design workshop</div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">View &rarr;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
        <h6 class="project_title">Festival</h6>
        <div class="project_name">Discover Milan's religious sites</div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">View &rarr;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
        <h6 class="project_title">Festival</h6>
        <div class="project_name">Saint Petersburg Philharmonic Orchestra</div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">View &rarr;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
        <h6 class="project_title">Festival</h6>
        <div class="project_name">Grand Hall Music </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">View &rarr;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="project_block slide no-padding">
        <h6 class="project_title">Festival</h6>
        <div class="project_name">Hand-made art & design workshop</div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">View &rarr;</a>
      </div>
      <!--       this button -->
      <div class="btn_container">
        <button class="more_posts">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe just set width to 100% after removing the button.

Comment: @wayneOS which width ?Body or project_block or another ?

Comment: from your slider, if i got your question right.

Comment: @wayneOS Should you tell me where I can write the width?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Consider using css media query to set `display: none` to the button you want to remove

2) Consider adding style `display: none` to the button upon resize using JS (totally bad idea)

3) Consider NOT TO remove button with js when you just need to hide it

4) Consider searching web before posting to SO

-------edit--------

just tried following, it hided btn successfully

```
@media screen and (max-width: 990px){
  .btn_container {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Spectr try snippet I've just added to the answer, hope it's what you're looking

Comment: Unfortunately same thing like in Matus Dubrava answer the button left white space .It just take 1 slide width but empty

Comment: @Spectr the button is actually a slide, am I correct?
So maybe you should also remove that slide?

Comment: @Spectr maybe you should move button out from slider? Try it on top of what I suggested